# Step to install dlib in centos 7

Tags: python, server, pip, centos7, dlib

I am trying to install `dlib` as one of python package in centos 7. I have tried to search the step to do that but most of the resources is showing the step to install in mac os and ubuntu. Is there a way to install it in centos ? or any resources will help me so much.
So far, I have been doing this: `pip3 install dlib` but I got this error:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] ....
```

and then I follow this instruction: (https://www.programmersought.com/article/62532018178/)

```
Command in the dlib-19.15 Contents:

mkdir build; cd build; cmake .. ; cmake --build .


then at dlib-19.15 directory, execute the command:

python setup.py install
```

at the last step.. by doing `python setup.py install` I get this error

```
[ 82%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/matrix.cpp.o
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/vector.cpp.o
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/svm_c_trainer.cpp.o
In file included from /home/wahyu-ppi/dlib-19.15/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/pytypes.h:12:0,
                 from /home/wahyu-ppi/dlib-19.15/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/cast.h:13,
                 from /home/wahyu-ppi/dlib-19.15/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/attr.h:13,
                 from /home/wahyu-ppi/dlib-19.15/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:43,
                 from /home/wahyu-ppi/dlib-19.15/dlib/../dlib/python/pybind_utils.h:6,
                 from /home/wahyu-ppi/dlib-19.15/dlib/../dlib/python.h:6,
                 from /home/wahyu-ppi/dlib-19.15/tools/python/src/opaque_types.h:6,
                 from /home/wahyu-ppi/dlib-19.15/tools/python/src/vector.cpp:4:
/home/wahyu-ppi/dlib-19.15/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/common.h:111:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
....
```

Comment: there must be more to that error message. also do you have python3 installed?

Comment: @drum I update my question, would you like to take a look?

Comment: @drum I have tried it just now and it works... Thank you so much for your help